# Copy-Item : The process cannot access the file

Tags: web-services, powershell, jenkins, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a Jenkins job which does below activity.

1. Stop WebService
2. Delete WebService
3. Copy items from Jenkins workspace to server path
4. Create WebService
5. Start WebService

Below is my PowerShell script:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Location\*"
$service = Get-Service -Name value -Computername $env:SERVER -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
sc.exe \\$env:SERVER stop value
Write-Host "value STOPPED"
sc.exe \\$env:SERVER delete val
Write-Host "val DELETED"
Copy-Item "C:\Location\*" "\\$env:SERVER\d$\Location" -Force -Recurse
sc.exe \\$env:SERVER create val start=auto DisplayName ="val"  binPath= D:\Location.exe
sc.exe \\$env:SERVER description value"value"
sc.exe \\$env:SERVER start value
Write-Host "value STARTED" 
if ($error) { exit 1 }
```

Error logs:

```
Copy-Item : The process cannot access the file '\\Location' because it is being used by another process.
At C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson2059984936352103941.ps1:18 char:5
+     Copy-Item "C:\Location\*" " ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

[SC] CreateService FAILED 1072:

The specified service has been marked for deletion.

[SC] ChangeServiceConfig2 FAILED 1072:

The specified service has been marked for deletion.

[SC] StartService FAILED 1058:

The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no
enabled devices associated with it.
```

Can you please help me out with this error? Do I need to restart the deploy server so that my process gets killed? If so I feel this is not relevant and cannot do in prod servers.

Comment: just find the process blocking the dll and stop it before

Comment: @4c74356b41 I am unable to find any process with that name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have another process which is using the dll. Since it is being used you cannot remove it. You need to make sure that no process is using your dll before you can remove it. To achieve this you will need to find out which process is using it, why it is using it and make sure that it will be closed. If the problem occurs next time as well, then you will need to add closing that process to your script.

Comment: Could you tell me how to achieve this

Comment: @Bhave view the list of processes, make a list of processes where you cannot exclude the usage of the dll. Try stopping them one-by-one and see when you can remove the dll. When you are able to do so, you will also know which process caused the problem. At this point, copy the dll back and restart the process to reproduce the issue. Adjust your script to your findings and make sure it works.